# angular 2 ngfor reverse order and same index

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an app that display an array items in panel 
using this code

```
<div *ngFor="let object of questionAnswer | reverse let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
        <p-panel header="{{object.question}}" [toggleable]="true" [collapsed]="true">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    {{object.answer}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <button type="button" class="paneltools btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"> </i> <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a (click)="editShow(i)">Edit</a></li>
                        <li><a (click)="remove(i)">Delete</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </p-panel>
    </div>
```

i wanted to display the items in reverse order as to show the newer item first and by using the a pipe code i found here works fine

```
export class ChallengesReversePipe {
transform(value) {
    return value.slice().reverse();
}
```

}

but my big problem is when doing it like this im getting a reverse index number and i need the original index number from before the inverse for example
the index for the top item should be the last index number in the array
and i cant seem to find a way to get it :(
any help please?

Comment: This seems counter intuitive.  You're modifying the collection (thus the index order as well) yet you want to keep the original index?  Don't use an index then...use an Id.

Comment: You could (inside the pipe) wrap the items in the array in objects like `{index: 1, value: item}` and then iterate over this returned array of objects and use the `object.id` as index.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
[attr.data-index]="questionAnswer.length - i - 1"
```

Answer (score 2):

`[attr.data-index]="questionAnswer.length - i - 1"` didn't work for me but I replaced all occurrences of `i` by `"yourArray.length - i - 1"` which did the job